# Passing the cell variable into the onclick method of a custom icon event Tabulator

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, tabulator, formatter

I'm using Tabulator to create tables. I have a delete icon (custom trash icon) for every row. But triggering `onclick` event on the custom icon isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
{formatter: deleteBtn, title:"Action"}

let deleteCallback = function(e, cell) {
        cell.getRow().delete();
};

let deleteBtn = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
        return `<span onclick="deleteCallback('${cell}')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>`;
};
```

The button is displayed correctly. However, when I click the button, I get an error stating: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRow')`. Basically `cell` is `undefined`.

There is an [cellClick](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/callbacks#cell) event which triggers action however I don't want that. I would like the button inside the cell to be clicked rather than the cell itself.

How do I get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own deleteButton formatter as.

```
Tabulator.extendModule(
  "format",
  "formatters",
  (function () {
    return {
      deleteButton: function (cell) {
      const deleteCallback = () => {
        cell.getRow().delete();
      };

     let span = document.createElement("span");
     let icon = document.createElement("i");
     icon.className = "fa fa-trash-o";

     icon.addEventListener("click", deleteCallback);
     span.append(icon);

     return span;
   },
};
})());
```

Here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/doublehrajput/pen/abLyBEY) for you

> Still I suggest to use "eventDelegation" for your code.

Comment: Thank you so much. Coincidentally, I solved my issue a while ago using your same methodology.